# xcode 10 - core data migration String to Int

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, xcode10, core-data-migration

I have this attribute **Country**

And it has an attribute **State** which is of type **String**, but should be **Int**

So I've created a new data-model version (checked with the green mark)

I also added this code to the **persistentContainer**:

```
    let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "Exchange")
    let description = NSPersistentStoreDescription()
    description.shouldMigrateStoreAutomatically = true
    description.shouldInferMappingModelAutomatically = true
    container.persistentStoreDescriptions = [description]
```

but when I **update** the app - it crashes:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Can't create support directory (can't create directory)'

from what I understand  - the auto-migration from String to Int is the reason for this...

how do I fix it?
do I need to do manual migration?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Have you added any attribute with Type 'Binary Data'? If yes, if you have check the Attributes for that attribute. If 'Allows External Storage' checkbox is checked, uncheck it and try to run the app again. That resolved the issue for me.

[image]

Comment: no, as the title implied - the attribute was String and I was to convert it to Int